# Selection in QLineEdit works in unusual way

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer

Im using QT 5.11. When I use standard "hold LMB + mouse moving" to select some text in QLineEdit it works in a way it shouldn't.

Suppose I start selection from the right and move a pointer (with LMB held down) to the left. Selection appears in a usual way. But if I place pointer under the line, selection disappears. And, if I place a pointer above the line, selection jumps to the left, selecting the whole text. It doesn't look like a standard behavior, since when you apply these actions on browser's url line, selection won't disappear when u place a pointer under the line.

I can derive from QLineEdit, trap mouse movement event and override selection behavior, but it will affect QLineEdits over the whole code in many and many files. So is it a way to force QLineEdit works in a usual way in QT Designer or something like that? Cuz it looks like its behavior is broken.

Comment: Maybe, installing an event filter (`installEventFilter`) could help you? Anyway, if you _subclass_ QLineEdit, why would it affect _all_ of them?

Comment: I mean subclassing QLineEdit with fixed selection behavior will require all QLineEdits to be replaced all over the code with such a subclass.

Comment: if i install an eventfilter, it will, again, require to set it up in all the QLineEdits.

Is this behavior a kinda QT 5.11 bug or am i doing something wrong? Does anyone else encouter this behaviour? Cuz in 5.9 QLineEdits seem to work fine.

Comment: well, my Qt 5.11 behaves that way in all text inputs, yes. Didn't notice it before. You could probably ease your solution via running recursively through widgets's children and searchg for all the QLineEdits (if eventfilter works), but yeah, looks a messy problem.

Comment: It's the same behavior for all apps in MacOS, at least: if you select a text and move the cursor under the line edit, it will select the text from the cursor to the end. If you move the cursor above the line, it will select the text from the cursor to the start.